# Does Matthew 16:28 imply that some from that biblical era would live many years?

Tags: matthew, kjv

Matthew 16:28

> Shall not taste death, till they see the Son of man coming in his kingdom.

At reading this verse my thought was, that some would live until the end days. Meaning even until these days.